# Keychain login password not working for Allow access

Tags: password, keychain

I'm working through iOS push notification setup and tried to export the private key as a Personal Information Exchange (.p12) cert and when I'm prompted for the "login" password it won't take it. I've tried changing the password and I'm able to do that successfully but not when I try to create the p12 file.

The OS X version is 10.11.2, and Keychain version 9.0 (55171.20.2)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so there was a detail that I didn't think was important, and apparently I was I wrong. I was connected to the system over VNC.

When I opened the system log and tried to perform the action over VNC I saw the entry "SecurityAgent: Ignoring user action since the dialog has recieved events from an untrusted source".

When I tried to perform the action on the system it self I was successful.